# what is the usage of : in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these code?

```
1- move : function(a,b){ 
.  
.  
.  

}  
2- function move(a,b){
.  
.  
.  
}
```

I know second part is a function but I don't know any thing about first part? Can you answer me about it?

Comment: I'm guessing there's more code in the first example, like a surrounding object literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/336859 may be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that functions in Javascript are themselves objects (and thus variables).

So these all accomplish the same thing:

1

```
var some_object = {};
some_object.do_something = function () {
    // function code
};
```

2

```
var some_object = {
    do_something: function () {
        // function code
    }
}
```

3

```
var some_object = {};
var some_function = function () {
    // function code
};
some_object.do_something = some_function;
```

4

```
var some_object = {};
function some_function () {
    // function code
};
some_object.do_something = some_function;
```

Only difference between those, which is probably irrelevant to you, is that 3 and 4 have a function called `some_function` in the outer scope. Otherwise they are identical.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example is invalid JavaScript by itself. You're probably seeing it as part of a very large object initialization in a library somewhere; i.e.:

```
var Library = {
  // ...lots of lines

  move: function(a, b) { /*...*/ },

  // ...lots more lines
};
```

In that case it's the same `:` you see in any property initialization. Same as this:

```
var object = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is part of an object (or should be) and defines a function as a property of that object, whereas the second defines the function `move()` in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

(1)`move` is usually a property, and you are assigning a function to that property. It is part of other code and not stand alone. Example:

```
var myObj = {
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log('Hello');
    },
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log('Bye');
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
obj.sayHello();
obj.sayBye();
```

(2) as you say, it is simply a function named `move`

You could therefore also 'combine' both:

```
function myHello(){
    console.log('Hello');
}

var myObj = {
    sayHello: myHello,
    sayBye: function() {
        console.log('Bye');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Colons are generally used to define properties in objects, e.g

```
obj = {
    myProp: "String",
    myFunc: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

console.log(obj.myProp);
obj.myFunc();
```

They are additionally used in ternary operators, e.g.

```
x = ( y >= 2 ) ? "greater" : "not greater";
```

is the same as

```
if (y >= 2)
{
    x = "greater";
}
else
{
    x = "not greater";
}
```

where the `?` is saying "if true then", and the `:` is the same as "else".

Answer (score 0):

Its essentially a difference between function expression and function declaration. You can read about this in detail on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#The_function_declaration_.28function_statement.29)

**tl:dr;**
One gets interpreted at load time and other gets interpreted at runtime.

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say that one gets [hoisted](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/) while the other does not (although the variable declaration is available in both cases).